# make distrot div with css or jquery

Tags: css

is this possible to make a div distort with rounded corners.
all the corner are different radius?

any jquery link or css
which will be cross browers
I try my best for the solution but dint find it 
any help

Answer (score 1):

Yes!! You can set different `border-radius` for all corner using css like this

```
div{
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:12px;
}
```

[Js Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/TQ3Xt/)

**Update**:
The effect of the picture which you have shared in your comment requires two properties of css
1. border-radius
2. transform

So here is code to achieve this

```
div
{
    border-top-left-radius:10px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:50px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
    background-color:Gray;
    height:200px;
    width:350px;
    transform:rotate(-15deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg); 
}
```

[Updated Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TQ3Xt/2/)

Comment: http://www.faisaljanjua.com/test.jpg

Comment: @x16 I have updated the answer. you can look into that

Answer (score 0):

You can do it [with CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)

```
div {
   border-radius: 1px 2px 3px 4px; /* top-left top-right bottom-right bottom-left */
}
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) is a very good resource for looking up css / js specs. For jquery use their [official docs](http://api.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

For cross browser you need to add all browser CSS definitions.

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 20px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 40px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 30px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/WVBTJ/

Comment: is this possible we can, do some irregular element
http://www.faisaljanjua.com/test.jpg
like this but the content in it will be normal